# Why can't I tuple unpack into scipy quad inside a penalty function?

Tags: python, syntax, scipy

So here's a basic example with some mixture distributions, where the number of parameters for 2 gaussians is already 6. For more distributions I want to penalize fits where the integral isn't 1.

`quad` from scipy refuses to take all parameters in one package, and instead I have to resort to `p[0],p[1]...` which quickly gets really bothersome.

Why can't I seem to unpack the tuple directly into the function here?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats as st
from scipy.integrate import quad
from scipy.optimize import leastsq
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def hist_to_xy(data, bins, normalized):
    counts, bin_edges = np.histogram(data, bins = bins, density = normalized)
    bin_centers = (bin_edges[1:] + bin_edges[:-1]) / 2

    x, y, = bin_centers, counts
    return x, y

# Random data
a = np.random.normal(0.3, 0.1, 1000)
b = np.random.normal(0.8, 0.1, 1000)
d = np.concatenate((a,b))
bins = np.arange(-0.5,1.5,0.01)
xvals = np.linspace(-0.2,1.2,100)
x, y, *_ = hist_to_xy(d, normalized = True, bins = bins)

def gauss(x, n1, m1, s1, n2, m2, s2):
    return n1*st.norm.pdf(x, m1,s1) + n2*st.norm.pdf(x, m2,s2)

### Works as you'd expect with p ####
p = (0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1)
integral, *_ = quad(gauss, 0, 1, args = p)

def residuals(p,x,y):
    ### Only works if you index everything manually in p as p[0], p[1], p[2]... ###
    integral, *_ = quad(gauss, 0, 1, args = (p[0],p[1],p[2],p[3],p[4],p[5])) # eurghhh
    penalization = abs(1-integral)*10000
    return y - gauss(x, *p) - penalization

popt, pcov = leastsq(func=residuals, x0 = (0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1), args=(x, y))
plt.plot(x,y, "o")
plt.plot(xvals, gauss(xvals, *popt), color = "firebrick")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the fix. Simply add `p = tuple(p)` inside the residuals function, and quad won't throw a complaint.

Comment: Yes, the `args` mechanism in these `scipy` functions depends on the parameter being a `tuple`.  But `p` as passed to `residuals` is an array (or may a list).  In some cases the 3 types are interchangeable; here they aren't.

Comment: A look inside the function reveals `if not isinstance(args, tuple): args = (args,)`. What exactly is the purpose of this then?

Comment: That turns it into a one element tuple.

Comment: `tuple([1,2,3]) => (1,2,3)` instead of `([1,2,3],)`.